# Best way to iterate over a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, iterator

I have a dataframe like so:

```
x  y  someVal someOtherVal
1  2  hello   heyhey
2  1  hello   heyhey
```

and want to iterate over each row to check if x < y, then append 'LT' to someVal to achieve this:

```
x  y  someVal someOtherVal
1  2  helloLT heyhey
2  1  hello   heyhey
```

I read in the documentation that iterating is not good practice and can lead to incorrect results, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: It's not that explicitly iterating will lead to *incorrect* results, but that it is highly inefficient, and sort of defeats the purpose of pandas. Use built-in vectorized operaitons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually explicit iteration can and should be avoided. The internal vectorized operations are much faster than Python `for` loops.

In this specific case, use

```
df.loc[df['x'] < df['y'], 'someVal'] += 'LT'
```

> Thanks! Is there a way to add the condition to only trigger the less than check if someVal == someOtherVal?

```
df.loc[(df['x'] < df['y']) & (df['someVal'] == df['someOtherVal']), 'someVal'] += 'LT'
```

or

```
df.loc[df['x'].lt(df['y']) & df['someVal'].eq(df['someOtherVal']), 'someVal'] += 'LT'
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add the condition to only trigger the less than check if someVal == someOtherVal?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df['someVal'] = df['someVal'] + np.where(df['x']<df['y'],'LT','')
```

Output:

```
   x  y  someVal someOtherVal
0  1  2  helloLT       heyhey
1  2  1    hello       heyhey
```

pandas will do this all in one vectorized step using index alignment.

Comment: Looks even like a rare opportunity for `Series.where`: `df['someVal'].where(df['x'] >= df['y'], df['someVal'] + 'LT')`